# How to parse double quotes in json ( a bit improper json )?

Tags: python, json

I am parsing a json as following :

```
["query", {
    "uid": "7E2M3",
    "text": "Whhe "Kaa", an a tron",
    "ops": [{
        "uid": "64H",
        "text": "Baa"
    }, {
        "uid": "1KR",
        "text": "Aa"
    }, {
        "uid": "CM1",
        "text": "Daa"
    }],
    "user_status": "20"
}]
```

The source of error :

```
    "text": "Whhe "
    Kaa ", an a tron",
```

On [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com/) I get the following error :

```
Error: Parse error on line 3:
...text": "Whhe "       Kaa ", an a tron", 
----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']', got 'undefined'
```

It's what is being sent by the server, and I don't know how to catch it ( if it's the right term ).

And it's not always that **double quotes** come into the json rather it's the first time, I've seen it .

Any proper way to handle this ?

*I'm using python to handle this .*

#### Thanks

Comment: This must be fixed on the server, it is not encoding JSON correctly. While there may or may not be a workaround possible on your side, incorrectly encoded JSON is *ambiguous* at best and your workaround could break at any time with different (incorrect) data.

Comment: The server is sending you invalid data. The best solution would be to contact someone and have them fix the server.

Comment: sorry, there was no newline. But isn't there any way to get the text, maybe some regex or using find command like str.find("text") , it will work obviously and then after removing the double quotes I load it as json ?

Comment: Its better you first approach to get well formed json input. Same Json data you need in below format -                                                                                    ["query", {
 "uid": "7E2M3",
 "text": "Whhe",
 "Kaaan": "a tron",
 "ops": [{
  "uid": "64H",
  "text": "Baa"
 }, {
  "uid": "1KR",
  "text": "Aa"
 }, {
  "uid": "CMAO48FK21",
  "text": "Brahmagupta"
 }],
 "user_status": "20"
}] If your team is ready to rectify this Json format problem so you need not to do special handling from your end.

Comment: Thanks a lot  however that's not my team sending the data, this is why there's the problem @Arpana